# Add spaces to the end of some Bash autocomplete options, but not to others?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, spaces

I'm trying to create a Bash completion script for a Java program.  A typical invocation of that program might look like this:

```
$ javaProgram -Dproperty=foo option1 option2
```

Part of my script will be to suggest the various Java properties that are available for this program (i.e., when the user types `-D`, the script would suggest, say, `property=`, allowing the user to then type the value).

I'd like the completion to not insert a space after the equals sign.  However, when the user is typing the various options for the program (`option1` and `option2` in the above example), I'd like the script to do the completion, and insert a space when it is completed.

I'm new to Bash completion scripting, but I'm aware of the `nospace` option for the `complete` shell builtin.  It doesn't seem to work for the `compgen` builtin, though, which seems like what I want.  I've tried using `nospace`, and then explicitly including spaces at the end of the appropriate options, but they don't seem to be making it through.

Does anyone know how to get spaces at the end of some options, but no spaces at the end of others?

Comment: Minimal answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66151065/6474744)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by removing spaces with the corresponding option, then add them back manually for the options where you want them, all using the simple `-W` ("wordlist") completion:

```
complete -o nospace -W 'Dproperty= "option1 " "option2 "' javaProgram
```

Autocompletion will now insert a space after `option1` and `option2`, but none after `Dproperty=`.

Answer (score 6):

The feature in in scp's bash completion mentioned by C4H5As that retains the added space is not the ampersand, that is just sed syntax for "replace with match".

You have to change the IFS so compgen does not split the input on spaces but on newlines or tabs:

```
local IFS=$'\t\n'
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$options" -- $cur) )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually alter the `complete` options using `compopt`. This worked for me:

```
_javaProgram(){
  # The completion will not add a space by default. We will alter
  # this behavior by calling `compopt +o nospace` to neutralize this.

  # In completion, '$2' is the current word, and '$3' is the previous
  case "$3" in
    -D) 
        # No space by default.
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "property=" -- "$2") )
    ;;
    *)  
        # The `case` default:
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "your default word list" -- "$2") )
        
        # append a space by calling:
        compopt +o nospace
    ;;
  esac
}

complete -F _javaProgram -o nospace javaProgram
```

However, I only needed space after short options. To contrast long and short options, you can check if there is a `=` in the `COMPREPLY` suggestions.

```
_javaProgram(){
  # The completion will not add a space by default. We will alter
  # this behavior by calling `compopt +o nospace` to neutralize this.

  # In completion, '$2' is the current word, and '$3' is the previous
  case "$3" in
    -D) 
        # Do not worry about appending spaces here ... .
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "property=" -- "$2") )
    ;;
    *)  
        # Do not worry about appending spaces here ... .
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "your default word list" -- "$2") )
    ;;
  esac

if [[ ! "${COMPREPLY[@]}" =~ "=" ]]; then
  # Add space if there is not a '=' in suggestions
  compopt +o nospace
fi
}

complete -F _javaProgram -o nospace javaProgram
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see the code you have so far.

However, look at the completion code for `scp` in `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` if you have that. It puts spaces after local filenames but not after hostnames.

Answer (score 1):

Dennis is right on the money, in the function you reference with `complete -F _your_func`, you want something like this (taken from /etc/bash_completion):

```
    # escape spaces; remove executables, aliases, pipes and sockets;
    # add space at end of file names
    COMPREPLY=( $( ssh -o 'Batchmode yes' $userhost \
               command ls -aF1d "$path*" 2>/dev/null | \
               sed -e "s/[][(){}<>\",:;^&!$&=?\`|\\ ']/\\\\\\\\\\\\&/g" \
               -e 's/[*@|=]$//g' -e 's/[^\/]$/& /g' ) )
    return 0
```

This particular example uses the `-o nospace` option but adds the space manually.  It's the last `-e ('s/[^\/]$/& /g')` that adds the space.  In this case it's adding only if the last parameter doesn't end in a slash (which would be a directory and have files to auto-complete).

The key difference seems to be adding an ampersand before the space.  Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

As the poster mentioned, it is not possible to pass the `-o nospace` option to `compgen`. One possibility is defining two functions where one inserts a call to `compopt -o nospace` before calling `compgen`  (the other function would not).

Example:

```
__my_complete_no_space() {
    local IFS=$' \t\n' cur_="${3-$cur}"
    [[ $cur_ == *:* ]] && cur_="${cur#*:}"
    compopt -o nospace
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -P "${2-}" -W "$1" -S "${4-}" -- "$cur_") )
}
```

This is useful when the addition of space (or not) depends on the context of what needs to be completed.

Comment: It is possible to pass options to `complete` using `compopt`. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66151065/6474744).