# Bash completions with equals sign and enumerable flag values

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion

I'm trying to construct a bash completion routine that will suggest command lines flags and suitable flag values. For example in the below **fstcompose** command I would like the competition routine to first suggest the **compose_filter=** flag, and then suggest possible values from [alt_sequence, auto, match, sequence].

```
fstcompose --compose_filter=
```

For any flags that do not have a set of associated of values I want the competition to fall back to the default mode of suggesting paths or files.

The one issue I'm facing is the = equal sign treated as an individual token and is set as the prev COMP_WORD. Is there a technique for detecting the whole flag before and including the previous = character ? Or is there a better way of implementing this type completion of flag with enumerable values? Below is a sample of the completion routine I'm working with.

```
_fstcompose()
{
  local cur prev opts filters pprev
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
  opts="--compose_filter= --connect"
  filters="alt_sequence auto match sequence"

  if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}))
  return 0
  fi

  if [[ ${prev} == "--compose_filter=" ]] ; then
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${filters}" -- ${cur}))
  return 0
  fi
  _filedir
}
complete -o nospace -F _fstcompose fstcompose
```

Comment: I made a similar question and an answer for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58156681/4414935). I could not mark this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Minimal answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66151065/6474744)

Answer (score 3):

Your first `return 0` prevents the second `if` from being evaluated. Try using a `case` statement ordered from most-specific to least-specific or at least order your `if` statements that way.

Since "=" is included in `$COMP_WORDBREAKS`, `${prev}` is "--compose_filter" without the "=".

If you remove "=" from `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` then `--compose_filter` is still `${cur}` rather than `${prev}`. Doing so without preserving and restoring its value will break other completions.

I'm not sure what other problems there may be.

You can pepper your function with `echo` statements that are redirected to another terminal to aid in debugging. For example:

```
echo "cur: $cur, prev: $prev" > /dev/pts/2
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help some people i think.
The below code should work (wrote on the fly)

```
have fstcompose &&{
    function elementExists(){
        local i isRunning result
        i=0
        isRunning=1
        result=0
        #~ for i in ${opts_with_equal[@]}; do
        while [ "$isRunning" -eq 1 ]; do
            if [ "$i" -ge "${#opts_with_equal[@]}" ]; then
                isRunning=0
            elif [ "${opts_with_equal[$i]}" == "$1" ]; then
                result=1
                isRunning=0
            fi
            ((i++))
        done
        echo $result
    }
    function _fstcompose(){
        local prev cur opts opts_with_equal isEqualOptions
        COMPREPLY=()
        _get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur prev
        opts="--compose_filter --connect"
        opts_with_equal=(--compose_filter)

        case ${cur} in
            '--compose_filter'*)
                prev="${cur%%=*}="
                cur=${cur#*=}
                COMPREPLY=( ${prev}$(compgen -W "alt_sequence auto match sequence" -- "${cur}") )
                return 0
                ;;
        esac

        if [[ "${cur}" != -* ]]; then
            _filedir
        else
            isEqualOptions=$(elementExists "${cur}")
            if [ "${isEqualOptions:-0}" -eq 1 ]; then
                COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -S '=' -- "${cur}") )
            else
                COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- "${cur}") )
            fi
        fi

    }
    complete -o nospace -F _fstcompose fstcompose
}
# Local variables:
# mode: shell-script
# sh-basic-offset: 4
# sh-indent-comment: t
# indent-tabs-mode: nil
# End:
# ex: ts=4 sw=4 et filetype=sh
```

Note: opts_with_equal it is an array in this example it contain only one parameter. Put into each parameter who use '='

Comment: What is that `have` in the beginning? I do not have such a command or function in my system.