# bash autocomplete script with symbols

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete, bash-completion

I have a binary which adds a user to management software called 'add_user'

Below is the code snippet for auto complete:

```
_add_user()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "type=admin type=poweruser" -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _add_user add_user
```

but when i am trying to autocomplete it stops at the '=' symbol as shown below:

```
add_user <TAB><TAB>
add_user type=
```

Can someone let me know what i missed here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash completions with equals sign and enumerable flag values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040883/bash-completions-with-equals-sign-and-enumerable-flag-values)

Comment: It seems like this isn't easily possible; the equal sign is treated as a word break by bash's autocomplete code.

Comment: You can remove the `=` char from `COMP_WORDBREAKS`: `COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//=/}`