# Complete command options with equal signs

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a Bash completion script for commands that can take long options on the form `--option` or `--param=value`. If the user has already entered an option on the command line, that option should be excluded from the completion list (assuming it only makes sense to specify a given option once on the command line).

Here is a first try:

```
_myprog()
{
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"

    local words=(--help --param1= --param-state --param2=)
    _exclude_cmd_line_opts
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${words[*]}" -- "$cur") )
}
complete -F _myprog myprog

_exclude_cmd_line_opts() {
    local len=$(($COMP_CWORD - 1))
    local i
    for i in "${COMP_WORDS[@]:1:$len}" ; do
         [[ $i == --* ]] && words=( "${words[@]/$i}" )
    done
}
```

If source this script `source script.sh` and then write:

```
$ myprog --param1= <tab><tab>
```

I get the following completion list:

```
=              --help         --param2=      --param-state
```

so it works almost except for that I get a spurious `'='` sign in the completion list.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change `--param1=` to `--param1` in the `local words` assignment.

Comment: Yes that works, but I would like to avoid having the user type the `=` sign if possible..

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the `=` at the beginning, not the `=` after `--param2`. I didn't see that before.

Comment: I cannot reproduce since I am in cygwin. However, what if you quote every argument in the array? `local words=("--help" "--param1=" ...)`. It looks like it sees `=` as another argument.

Comment: @fedorqui It does not help. I think it might be related to COMP_WORDBREAKS ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash completions with equals sign and enumerable flag values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040883/bash-completions-with-equals-sign-and-enumerable-flag-values)

Comment: See also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58156681/4414935)

Comment: You can just remove the `=` in `COMPREPLY` using `sed`, `awk`, etc. Also, if you want to append space to short option suggestions but not to the long options, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66151065/6474744)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering an equal sign on the command line forces a word break due to the default content of `COMP_WORDBREAKS`. The effect seems to be that the equal sign enters as a separate word in `COMP_WORDS`. This is exploited in the following modification of `_exclude_cmd_line_opts`:

```
_exclude_cmd_line_opts() {
    local len=$(($COMP_CWORD - 1))
    local i
    for ((i=1 ; i<=len; i++)) ; do
        local j="${COMP_WORDS[$i]}"
        if [[ $j == --* ]] ; then
            (( i<len )) && [[ ${COMP_WORDS[$(( i + 1))]} == '=' ]] && j="$j="
            words=( "${words[@]/$j}" )
        fi
    done
}
```

The problem with the original version of `_exclude_cmd_line_opts` was that  `${words[@]/$j}` would give a spurious `=` when for example `words=(param1=)` and `j="param1"` (note the missing trailing equal sign in `$j` which was caused by `COMP_WORDBREAKS`)..

**Update**

I discovered another peculiarity with this. The cases above worked fine because I never had to type `<tab>` immediately after an `=` sign. However, if for example `words=(--param= --param-info)` and I type `--par<tab>` there is still two candidate completions and the current words is only partially completed to become `--param`. At this I would like to select the first of the two candidates, and I type an explicit `=` sign on the command line and then type `<tab>` what happens now is that Bash thinks that you have typed a space (since COMP_WORDBREAKS contains `=`) and the current completion word changes from `--param=` to `=`. This again, will make Bash readline omit insert the usual space, so the user is forced to type a space to continue completing next option.

It is possible to avoid having to type a space in the above case, by returning a `COMPREPLY` array with an empty string.

```
_myprog()
{
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"
    local prev=""
    (( COMP_CWORD > 0 )) && prev="${COMP_WORDS[$(( COMP_CWORD - 1))]}"
    [[ $cur == '=' && $prev == --* ]] && { COMPREPLY=( "" ); return; }

    local words=(--param= --param-info)
    _exclude_cmd_line_opts
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${words[*]}" -- "$cur") )
}
```

Comment: This is what I would do too. (I played around but you answered earlier.) :)  Also it seems there is no other way then post-sanitize this, since you already mentioned that setting `COMP_WORDBREAKS` could affect the behaviour of other programs.

Comment: Suppose you have two options `--opt` and `--opt-suffix`. If you type `myprog --opt <tab>` then `-suffix` will be completed as a separate word.

Comment: Also `--param=-<tab>` expands to `--param=--param-info`

Answer (score 1):

This solution takes advantage of `_init_completion` function. It does not complete arguments for options that take such. It also accepts long options in form `--param value`. This does not examine line after cursor position for excluding options, but it could be modified to take into account whole command line, if needed.

```
_exclude_cmd_line_opts() {
    local i w j skip= sep_arg
    for ((i=1 ; i<cword; i++)) ; do
        [[ $skip ]] && { skip=; continue; }
        w=${words[$i]}
        if [[ $w == --* ]] ; then
            [[ $w == --?*=* ]] && {
                w=${w%%=*}
                sep_arg=
            } || sep_arg=1
            for j in ${!options[@]}; do
                [[ ${options[$j]%=} == $w ]] && {
                    [[ ${options[$j]} == *= && $sep_arg ]] && skip=1
                    unset -v options[$j]
                    break
                }
            done
        fi
    done
}

_myprog()
{
    IFS=$'\n'
    local cur prev words cword split # needed by _init_completion()
    # Do not treat = as word breaks even if they are in $COMP_WORDBREAKS:
    # Split option=value into option in $prev and value in $cur
    _init_completion -s || return 

    local options=(--param= --param-info --opt --opt-suffix)
    [[ $prev == --param ]] && { COMPREPLY=( ); return 0; }
    _exclude_cmd_line_opts

    local i
    for i in ${!options[*]}; do [[ ${options[$i]} == *= ]] || options[$i]+=' ' ; done
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${options[*]}" -- "$cur") )
    compopt -o nospace
} && complete -F _myprog myprog
```